# my A tag is not setting the width to the parent inside of a <td> tag

Tags: jquery, css

my fiddle is located at:

http://jsfiddle.net/9QHpP/

I am trying have the width of the anchor tag be the size of the TD it is contained in.  Setting width to 100% or inherit isnt working, nor is jquery to set the width.

How do you do it?  Is it possible?  I tried more then a few ways already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to `a` tag.

```
a {
  background-color: blue;  
  display: block;       
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9QHpP/1/)***

***OR***

```
a {
  background-color: blue;  
  display: inline-block;       
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9QHpP/3/)***

Comment: So i dont spam questions, what about setting the alignment of an a tag in a td tag?  I was trying margin and text-align but those Might not be working..   For something that isnt block.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the display style of the link to either `block` or `inline-block` and it should work:

```
a{
   background-color: blue;   
   display:block;
}
```

[Here is your modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/9QHpP/2/)